# Automatically changing the font size in a Swing component as the string length increases

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a `JTextField` that displays a line number like this : 2 or 2.1 or 2.1.1 etc. I would like the size of the `JTextField` to always stay the same but I want the font size to decrease/increase so that the text is always fully displayed and it fills the text field.

I'm wondering if there's a simple way to do this (I don't mind using a different swing component) or will I have to do it manually i.e. by checking the size of the text and changing the text field size?

I'd obviously prefer not to do it this way since the size increment may not be a nice number to go from e.g. 2.1 to 2.1.1.

Comment: It would not be difficult to set up a precomputed (table!) function determining the font size for a given field length so that a combination of digits and periods can be accomodated. AFAIK, digits have the same width in all fonts.

Comment: @laune that's completely untrue and arbitrary. Although many fonts will have the same width for all digits, some fonts have different width for digits, and there is no rule that all digits of a font should have the same width (same thing goes for any glyph of any font). Digit '1' in "Comic Sans MS" is much narrower than other digits, for example

Comment: @GuillaumePolet  Fonts that don't have the same width for all digits aren't useful for displaying number tables and rarely used for the kind of display work OP appears to be related to. But thanks for the hint - I qualify my statement that some "comic" fonts disallow this approach. (BTW, I was not aware that OP was not aware of stringWidth, which I would have proposed in the first place.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any component performing this, but you can write it yourself by extending `jTextField` and using 
[FontMetrics.stringWidth()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#stringWidth-java.lang.String-)
to determine the font size (e.g. on overloaded `setText`).

Comment: Isn't this what OP prefers *not* to do?

Comment: It is, but I just wanted to suggest, that it is not a difficult task, so it may be faster to write it than to search for it.

Comment: Thanks, that actually makes things much easier and writing the method will be quite simple.

Comment: Overriding `setText` seems quite fragile. Adding a `DocumentListener` to the `Document` of the textfield would be much more robust and appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

> the JTextField becomes smaller as the font decreases.

The preferred size of the text field is based on the font. So the size will increase/decrease as the font size changes. Override the `getPreferredSize()` method of `JTextField` to provide your own implementation.

Maybe something like:

```
Font current = getFont();
setFont( UIManager.getFont("TextField.font") );
Dimension preferred = super.getPreferredSize();
setFont( current );
return preferred;
```